# I don't know why last case (Default) doesn't work

Tags: java

I did everything correct except that fails me with the option "Default" every time when I try a number greater than 7

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.println("Introduzca un numero correspondiente al día de la semana");
int día = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

if (día >= 1 && día <= 7) {
    switch (día) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("El día introducido es Lunes");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("El día introducido es Martes");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("El día introducido es Miércoles");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("El día introducido es Jueves");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("El día introducido es Viernes");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("El día introducido es Sábado");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("El día introducido es Domingo");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("El día introducido no es válido");
            break;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"?

Comment: Please show your full code.I thing removing your if block will give you desired results.

Comment: You are only taking care of `dia` values between 1 and 7, all possibilities are already covered by your `case` statements, the `default` one will never be called .

Comment: Your answer is here: `if (día >= 1 && día <= 7)`

Comment: it can never reach that code because of the if statement

Comment: You have made the `default` case obsolete by the condition in the `if` statement before.

Comment: And by the way, why you want the if statement there?

Answer (score 2):

If you enter a number greater than 7 the code will not enter in the if block and so will not go in the switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the IF block in the top. Then it will give default output for invalid dates.